# How to make a vector that follows a certain trend?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I have a set of data with over 4000 points. I want to exclude grooves from them, ideally from the point from which they start. The data look for example like this:

[image]

The problem with this is the noise I get at the top of the plateaus. I have an idea, in which I would take an average value of the most common within some boundaries (again, ideally sth like the red line here:

[image]

and then I would construct a temporary matrix, which would fill up one by one with Y if they are less than this average. If the Y(i) would rise above average, the matrix would find its minima and compare it with the global minima. If the temporary matrix's minima wouldn't be sth like 80% of the global minima, it would be discarded as noise.

I've tried using mean(Y), interpolating and fitting it in a polynomial (the green line) - none of those method would cut it to the point I would be satisfied.

I need this to be extremely robust and it doesn't need to be quick. The top and bottom values can vary a lot, as well as the shape of the plateaus. The groove width is more or less the same.

Do you have any ideas? Again, the point is to extract the values that would make the groove.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by grooves ?

Comment: In those case the parts of the plot which would be far deeper, than the most of the plot. In this example I would have 10 grooves.

Comment: if you just want to identify the "grooves" you could just make a simple mean and standard deviation and then parse your data. basically: grooves=S<(mean(S)-std(S)*2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a [median filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter)?

Let's define some noisy data similar to yours, and plot it in blue:

```
x = .2*sin((0:9999)/1000);                         %// signal
x(1000:1099) = x(1000:1099) + sin((0:99)/50*pi);   %// noise: spike
x(5000:5199) = x(5000:5199) - sin((0:199)/100*pi); %// noise: wider spike
x = x + .05*sin((0:9999)/10);                      %// noise: high-freq ripple
plot(x)
```

Now apply the median filter (using [`medfilt2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/medfilt2.html) from the Image Processing Toolbox) and plot in red. The parameter `k` controls the filter memory. It should chosen to be large compared to noise variations, and small compared to signal variations:

```
k = 500; %// filter memory. Choose as needed
y = medfilt2(x,[1 k]);
hold on
plot(y, 'r', 'linewidth', 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is MAGNIFICENT!

I tried this with k = 400, this is the result I got: http://imgur.com/o1u5kvY

This is of course nice, but you can see the plot going down a bit at the end. Can you explain this somehow?

Comment: OK, figured it out myself. I've increased the k factor a bit and add `symmetric` as an argument of the function. It is awesome right now, thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad it works for you! I didn't know about the `'symmetric'` argument

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't have the image processing toolbox and can't use `medfilt2` a method that's more manual. Skip the extreme values, and do a [curve fit](http://www.mathworks.se/help/curvefit/fit.html) with `sin1` as curve type. *Note that this will only work if the signal is in fact a sine wave!*

```
x = linspace(0,3*pi,1000);
y1 = sin(x) + rand()*sin(100*x).*(mod(round(10*x),5)<3);
y2 = 20*(mod(round(5*x),5) == 0).*sin(20*x);
y = y1 + y2;  %// A messy sine-wave
yy = y;       %// Store the messy sine-wave
[~, idx] = sort(y);  
y(idx(1:round(0.15*end))) = y(idx(round(0.15*end)));  %// Flatten out the smallest values
y(idx(round(0.85*end):end)) = y(idx(round(0.85*end)));%// Flatten out the largest values

[foo goodness output] = fit(x.',y.', 'sin1'); %// Do a curve fit
plot(foo,x,y)   %// Plot it
hold on
plot(x,yy,'black')
```

[image]

Might not be perfect, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: This seems to be a good solution. But does the `'sin1'` option produce a sine output? Because in that case, if the data is not sinusoidal it might not be able to find a good fit (I don't have the `fit` function in Matlab R2010b so I can't test)

Comment: Yes, it finds a sine wave approximation, so if the data is not periodic, this approach won't work. The signal OP included looks sinusoidal though. +1 by the way, your approach seems like the way to go if you have the image processing toolbox. =)

Comment: Thanks! I'd give you +1 if you included a disclaimer in your question saying the fit curve is a sinusoid. I think it's an important restriction that should be pointed out

Comment: @Ropert P.,  @Luis Mendo is right, my data is not always sinusoidal, in fact, it most commonly is not, those plateus should be flat, since it's a surface of a polymer chip :)

Thanks for the input, I didn't know about `fit` either :)